# pandas: create a column from 1 to length of each group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that has groups. For each group I would like to form a new column that contains integers from 1 to the number of rows in that group. The following attempt doesn't work as it creates one row with multiple columns instead of one column with multiple rows. Why does this happen?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"a": np.arange(5), "b": np.arange(5)[::-1], "id": [1,1,1,2,2]}).set_index("id")
df["c"] = df.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: np.arange(1, len(x)+1))
```

Alternatively if I try to return a `Series` object as in:

```
df["c"] = df.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: pd.Series(data = np.arange(1, len(x)+1)))
```

This raises an exception saying the indices are incompatible (which makes sense since the returned `Series` now has a `MultiIndex`)

**Update**: Let me make this question a bit more general: how does one do `groupby` on a dataframe returning a `Series` with the same index as the dataframe so that the resulting series can be merged into the original dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df["c"] = 1 + df.groupby("id").cumcount()
```

The reason your solutions do not work is that groupby & agg try to create a result for each **group**, not for each **row**. So the following create a list of numbers for each group

```
df.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: np.arange(1, len(x)+1))
```

---

To your comment: To have `the numbers in reverse` you can do `groupby - sort - cumcount`.

For more general need, you may want to check out `rolling / resample` functions.

---

> Let me make this question a bit more general: how does one do groupby
>   on a dataframe returning a Series with the same index as the dataframe
>   so that the resulting series can be merged into the original
>   dataframe?

You need `groupby + transform`. <s>But it will not work for cumulative operation cases like this.</s> Actually it can, as shown in @Alex answer

```
df["c"] = df.groupby("id")["a"].transform(lambda x: np.arange(1, len(x)+1))
```

Comment: this solves the problem but very narrowly. what if i wanted the numbers in reverse or somsething.. please provide a more general solution, if possible.

Comment: appreciate the answer, please take a look at the updated question. again, i want to return a series for each group and then merge it back into the dataframe. rolling/resample is not applicable in this context

Comment: `groupby` + `transform` is the right solution here. i'll post it as the answer, if you want to edit yours to match i'll accept it since you had the idea

Comment: Actually I didn't know we can use `transform` like that. So feel free to accept your own solution.

Comment: you had the idea so i don't mind giving you credit (and learned something new, like me)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the right approach that is fairly general:

```
df["c"] = df.groupby("id")["a"].transform(lambda x: np.arange(1, len(x)+1))
```