# Subsample abundance dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with species as columns and site as rows.  In each cell is the number of each species I saw at that site.  e.g.

```
    Fern1   Fern2   Flower1 Flower2
Site1   15  0   6   1
Site2   0   46  16  40
Site3   25  1   19  3
```

total = 172
But I want to randomly subsample 100 individuals from this dataset:

```
    Fern1   Fern2   Flower1 Flower2
Site1   10  0   3   0
Site2   0   26  10  26
Site3   14  0   10  1
```

(this example not random, but what I want is random)

so I started by doing

```
df.stack()
df[df != 0]
```

```
Site1   Fern1   15
        Flower1 6
        Flower2 1
Site2   Fern2   46
        Flower1 16
        Flower2 40
```

***This is the part I need help on***
Now I want to make groups from 1:len(count)
e.g.

```
Site1  Fern1  1     1
              2     1
              3     1
              4     1
              ...   ...
              16    1
      Flower1 1     1
```

So that I can use python sample.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634224/pandas-create-a-column-from-1-to-length-of-each-group) but it doesn't *quite* do what I want.  Any help would be appreciated.  I tried to look as much as possible since this is a pretty common problem but am in a bit of a hurry and thought someone might have done this already.

Thanks in advance.

[pandas: create a column from 1 to length of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634224/pandas-create-a-column-from-1-to-length-of-each-group)

`result = df.groupby(df.index).transform(lambda x: np.arange(1,len(x)+1))`

The above just gave a bunch of [1] in my column, with the original index.

Answer (score 0):

Try look at `cumcount`

```
yyy = df.groupby(t.index).cumcount()+1
```

Comment: Thanks. This give a bunch of 2s in my result, but I noticed a typo in my previous post so perhaps the edited post will clarify what I previously tried.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is what I wound up doing (after turning my stacked df from a series back to a df with a column named 'Counts'):

```
    d = {}
    for i in df.index:
         x = np.arange(0, df['Counts'].loc[i]) +1
         d[i] = pd.DataFrame([[1]*len(x),], index= [i], columns = x)
         d[i].index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(r[i].index.get_level_values(0))
         d[i] = d[i].stack()

    z = pd.concat(d.values(), axis=0)
```

While this works, it is not very efficient and I get a memory error when I try to sample 100k rows. Any suggestions to process a giant file in this way?

Thanks to everyone that provided answers. I welcome your feedback.